# Add generated files in Rubymine to git

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, rubymine

I just started using Rubymine, on a project that is stored in a git repository. According to https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/help/adding-files-to-version-control.html I should get a popup when adding new files to the project, to add the new file in the index. When I manually create a file, that popup is indeed showing.

However, when I generate new files (Tools | Run Rails Generator) I don't get that option. Even enabling "Add Silently" won't help. Am I missing a setting, or is it something I should get used to?

Comment: I see same behaviour. I just add all from project root before committing, but have not investigated

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the generated files are generated in a folder ignored by a `.gitignore` file.

To check that, do in command-line, type (for a given generated file):

```
cd /path/to/repo
git check-ignore -v -- path/to/generated/file
```

Comment: The folder the generated files are stored in, is not in my .gitignore. When I add a file by hand in the same folder, I do get the option to add it to git.

Comment: Did you try the git check-ignore -v on a file that is not proposed to be added?

Comment: I add a test-migration file through RubyMine and ran a git check-ignore -v on the newly created file. The output was empty, which is what was expected (it's not empty on a file that is ignored).

Comment: What version of git are you using?

Comment: @pietmarcus can you check if the issue persists after upgrading git to 2.7.2?